# Insert is 10 times faster than Update in Cassandra. Is it normal?

Tags: cassandra

In my Java application accessing Cassandra, it can insert `500 rows` per second, but only update `50 rows` per second(actually the updated rows didn't exist).

Updating one hundred fields is as fast as updating one field.

I just use `CQL statements` in the Java application.

Is this situation normal? How can I improve my application?

```
public void InsertSome(List<Data> data) {

    String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Data (E,D,A,S,C,......) values(?,?,?,?,?,.............); ";
    if (prepared == null)
        prepared = getSession().prepare(insertQuery);

    count += data.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {

        List<Object> objs = getFiledValues(data.get(i));
        BoundStatement bs = prepared.bind(objs.toArray());
        getSession().execute(bs);
    }
}

public void UpdateOneField(Data data) {
    String updateQuery = "UPDATE Data set C=? where E=? and D=? and A=? and S=?; ";

    if (prepared == null)
        prepared = getSession().prepare(updateQuery);

    BoundStatement bs = prepared.bind(data.getC(), data.getE(),
            data.getD(), data.getA(), data.getS());
    getSession().execute(bs);
}

public void UpdateOne(Data data) {
    String updateQuery = "UPDATE Data set C=?,U=?,F........where E=? and D=? and A=? and S=? and D=?; ";

    if (prepared == null)
        prepared = getSession().prepare(updateQuery);
    ......
    BoundStatement bs = prepared.bind(objs2.toArray());
    getSession().execute(bs);
}
```

**Schema:**

```
Create Table Data (
  E,
  D,
  A,
  S,
  D,
  C,
  U,
  S,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY ((E
  D),
  A, 
  S)
)  WITH compression =  { 'sstable_compression' : 'DeflateCompressor', 'chunk_length_kb' : 64 }
    AND compaction =  { 'class' : 'LeveledCompactionStrategy' };
```

**Another scenario**:

I used the same application to access another cassandra cluster. The result was different. UPDATE was as fast as INSERT. But it only INSERT/UPDATE 5 rows per second. This cassandra cluster is the DataStax Enterprise running on GCE(I used the default DataStax Enterprise on Google Cloud Launcher)
So I think it's probably that some configurations are the reasons. But I don't know what they are.

Comment: Could you post the schema of your table here too?

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually UPDATE and INSERT are the same so I would expect similar performance.  UPDATE doesn't check to see if the data already exists (unless you are doing a lightweight transaction with `IF EXISTS`).

I noticed that each of your methods prepare a statement if it is not null.   Is it possible the statement is being reprepared each time?  That would add for a roundtrip for every method invocation.   I also noticed that `InsertSome` does multiple inserts per invocation, where `UpdateOne` / `UpdateOneField` execute one statement.   So if the statement were prepared every time, thats an invocation per update, where it's only done once per insert for a list.

Comment: I used the same application to access another cassandra cluster. The result was different. UPDATE was as fast as INSERT. But it only INSERT/UPDATE 5 rows per second. This cassandra cluster is the DataStax Enterprise running on GCE(I used the default DataStax Enterprise on Google Cloud Launcher)

Answer (score -1):

Cassandra uses log-structured merge trees for an on-disk format, meaning all writes are done sequentially (the database is the append-only log). That implies a lower write latency.

At the cluster level, Cassandra is also able to achieve greater write scalability by partitioning the key space such that each machine is only responsible for a portion of the keys. That implies a higher write throughput, as more writes can be done in parallel.